# spaCy BERT dictionary

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-transformers

I am trying to access spaCy BERT dictionary, but I receive strange output from the model. For instance for `en_core_web_lg` model I can extract ~1.3 million tokens like this

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") 
tokens = [t for t in nlp.vocab]
```

When I do the same for `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg` model I only get 478 tokens,

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg") 
tokens = [t for t in nlp.vocab]
```

while there should be ~30k tokens according to [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf). Is there a way I can access them via `nlp.vocab` or via [custom component attributes](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with standard models like "en". Interestingly enough the length is exactly the same.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en")
len([t for t in nlp.vocab])
478
```

Turned out that models like "en" does not contain the real vectors (see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1520 ). So I guess this is also the case for Bert.